# Azure AD user login to an app fails even after admin consent is given for the multitenant app

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, outlook, azure-active-directory

I have registered a sample multi-tenant app in azure portal app registration requiring certain permissions to access outlook mails. I also have a SAAS application which uses this app and requests for oauth token from users to read and send emails using outlook.

There is a tenant with a set of users who want to use my app for configuring emails in the SAAS application. But the users in the tenant do not have admin privileges to give consent to the application. Based on [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-admin-consent-workflow), admin has to give consent to the application using the v2-permissions-and-consent

Admin has given consent to the application by using the following URL:

> [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant) ID}/v2.0/adminconsent?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxb&state=12345&redirect_uri=https://c9713e1c5859.ngrok.io/auth/outlook/callback&scope=https://outlook.office.com/User.Read https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send&response_type=code

Admin consented permissions:
[consented permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPUBu.png)

Even after admin gives consent to all the permissions that the app requests and adds the users to the configured enterprise application in Azure AD, the users are shown the approval prompt when they try to login to the application.

Approval prompt shown to the users :
[approval prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVwZc.png)

Ideally, once the app is approved in Azure AD Enterprise Applications, all the other users in the tenant should be able to use the application without any consent requirement.

The oauth URL that users use to login is

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fc9713e1c5859.ngrok.io%2Fauth%2Foutlook%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=offline_access+https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2FUser.Read+https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2FIMAP.AccessAsUser.All+https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2FSMTP.Send&state=5bfc1a7683bfa19468e7d4d67fc6893e5a00f93efe31ca51

Could anyone help me understand what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

**It should be agreed by the target tenant administrator, and then use the target tenant to log in.**

## In below url, you should have used wrong  `{tenant ID}`, it should be target tenant id. Not the tenant id where your app is located.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant ID}/v2.0/adminconsent?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxb&state=12345&redirect_uri=https://c9713e1c5859.ngrok.io/auth/outlook/callback&scope=https://outlook.office.com/User.Read https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send&response_type=code
```

I have tested it, then reproduced your problem. If you need further help, please let me know.

Comment: I used the target tenant ID only for this URL. Not the tenant ID in which the app is located.

Comment: @FarithaNasreen Does your login user belong to the target tenant?

Comment: @FarithaNasreen You replace `common` in url2 with your `target tenant id` and try it. Check whether the user belongs to the target tenant.

Comment: I tried replacing common with target tenant id in URL2 and logging into the target tenant using a user from the target tenant. Still getting the same approval required pop up.

Comment: if my app is unverified, will there be a issue?

Comment: @FarithaNasreen What does `unverified` mean?

Comment: when the app is not published by a verified publisher, the app will be showing unverified publisher on the consent screen.

Comment: @FarithaNasreen You need click `Enterprise App` to find your app by name or application id on portal in  the target tenant .

Comment: @FarithaNasreen Remember to select the Application Type as All in the target tenant AD. If the app does not exist, then the authorization to the target tenant failed. Please try authorization again.

Comment: I checked in enterprise applications. the app is available with all permissions consented to.